# Fixing an image to top right but setting a min page width

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to affix a callout image to the top right of a page, but I do not want it moving once the screen is below a certain width or else it will begin to overlap other page elements. Does anyone know what the best way of going about this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS practises tell us that each element on the page should be encapsulated as a block:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="picture.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This kind of style allows elelments to stack on top of one another, preventing overlap.

In your case, it sounds like you have a header, and you need a picture fixed in the top right:

```
<div id="header" style="width:100%;float:left;">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="picture.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- continue stacking elements to build your page -->

<div id="content" style="width:100%;float:left;">
    Hey, this stuff works!
</div>
```

But you also mentioned your page should have a min width, so that when a user tries to contract the width, elements do not overlap horizontally:

```
<body style="min-width:800px;">

    <div id="header" style="width:100%;float:left;">
        <div style="float:right;">
            <img src="picture.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- continue stacking elements to build your page -->

    <div id="content" style="width:100%;float:left;">
        Hey, this stuff works!
    </div>

</body>
```